# Где продать мобильное приложение, которое забанят в google play и amazon store

Tags: android, google-play

Написал мобильное приложение (игру). Хотел выложить игру в самые популярные магазины, но её недопускают из за того что там чужой контент. 
В игре используются фотки персонажей marvel и других вселенных.

Посоветуйте все возможные магазины, где игру пропустят и не забанят из за подобныйх мелочей. И не важно что магазин не популярен, мне тупо нужно место где продать.

Не советуйте делать свой сайт и прикручивать платежные агрегаторы - не вариант, вообще не шарю в этом.

Comment: Украденный чужой труд - мелочь. Дожили...

Answer (score 1):

Вот эти всё подряд разрешают публиковать:

1. [Aptoide](https://ru.aptoide.com/).
2. [Opera Mobile Store](http://android.oms.apps.bemobi.com).

Comment: А как в этих магазинах с выводом денег. Нужно будет ИП регистрировать, оформлять договор с компанией и тд ?. Или можно сразу вывести. Насколько я слышал в google play вывод это целый геморой.

Comment: @SomeHuman в этом плане я не в курсе. Я там заливал бесплатные игры с рекламой.